# Работа конструкции List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java

List является интерфейсом, и по идее, мы не можем создавать объект типа интерфейс, но почему тогда работает конструкция

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

ArrayList является классом, здесь понятно, но почему тогда можно создавать объект класса ArrayList типа List, когда мы в принципе не можем создать никакой объект типа интерфейс ?

Comment: Вы создаёте объект класса `ArrayList`  - вы **не** создаёте объект класса `List`. Однако так как `ArrayList` реализует интерфейс `List`, то с объектом класса `ArrayList` можно работать и как с `List`. В том числе присваивать его в переменную, объявленную как `List`

Comment: Т.е. поучается, когда класс реализует определённый интерфейс, мы можем работать с ним как с интерфейсом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете объект типа ArrayList, но **рассматриваете** его как List.
Т.е. Вы можете без приведения типа использовать только те его методы, которые переопределяют методы интерфейса List.

Возьмем пример:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

В таком коде Вы можете воспользоваться методом `list2.trimToSize()`. А у list1 такого метода нет (вернее - есть, но нужен явный cast).
Т.е. объект-то у нас в обоих случаях ArrayList, но рассматриваем мы его в первом случае как просто некий List, а во втором - именно как ArrayList и ничто иное.

В большинстве случаев коллекциям вполне достаточно методов, определяемых соответствующими интерфейсами и подход с объявлением типа как интерфейс - предпочтительный.